# getParamter() returns NULL

Tags: java, forms, jsp, post

Why is `request.getParameter("termin");` returning `NULL`
.The Connection and the Statement for my Databse are correct.It works fine in an more simple Version.
This is JSp/JAva Code:

```
int result = 0;
if(request.getParameter("submit") != null) {
    String name = new String();

    if(request.getParameter("termin") != null) {
        name = request.getParameter("termin");

    }else {
        out.println("termin is null");
    }
    Termin t1 = new Termin();
    result = t1.setTermin(name);
```

Here is the HTML Code :

```
<form action="index.jsp" method="POST" name="test">
    <div class="modal fade" id="bModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="beispielModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Schließen</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="beispielModalLabel">Neuer Termin</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <!-- <form role="form" action="index.jsp" method="POST"> -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="empfaenger-name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empfaenger-name" name="termin" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nachricht-text" class="control-label">Zusätzlich:</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="nachricht-text"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    <!--  </form> -->
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">          
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="del" data-dismiss="modal" >Löschen</button>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="eintrag" data-dismiss="modal" value="Speichern" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*It works fine in an more simple Version.*"? Can you show some code about it?

Comment: change the form method from POST to GET, submit it and verify that you can see key/value in the URL.

Comment: @Ihsan
<code><form action="InsertData.jsp" method="POST">

 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Neuer Termin:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="termin" value="" size="50"/></td>
   </tr>

  
  </tbody>
 
 
 
 </table>
  <button type="submit">Einfügen</button>
  <input type="submit" value="Einfügen" name="submit"/>
  <input type="reset" value="Delete" name="delete"/>

</form></code>

Shit :D . The html file in the simple Version ist just a table with an Input and its adding the Data perfectly into the Database

Comment: Hmm, nothing to see there actually. You could try changing the method from `POST` to `GET`, like @alfasin commented.

Comment: I did, nothing changes ;) yeah this kind of weird, i checked all "names" again and again und its still null....

Comment: @lolio this check doesn't suppose to "fix" the issue, it'll simply show you if the parameter is passed from the form to the request or not.

Comment: Ah i understand, you are right, its not even passed.I used a slightly different html Version of my uper-Code, without CSS and it works...

Comment: @alfasin <br/> If i dont use data-dismiss="modal" in my Submit Button, the Data will be passed, but its an empty String....

Comment: @alfasin ok i found the Problme, the ID="Eintrag" caused my Problem, if i remove the id of the submit Button, it works fine.Maybe you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Bootstrap expert yet I can see a few potential causes to this issue:

- `data-dismiss="modal"`- looking at:
  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target it seems that `data-dismiss="modal"` is used only with "close" buttons - never with "submit"!
- the class `class="btn btn-primary"` is supposed to be used with elements of type `button` and you're using it with `input`
- using the `id` attribute might create a conflict with bootstrap autogenerated html-elements, but I'm just guessing here based on your comment above.